# How to update a particular input field among dynamically created input fields in JavaScript, ajax from PHP response?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I want to update a particular input field from ajax response where the ajax would do query from that selected field and update the field.

```
<input class = "someclass" id="id1"></input>
<input class = "someclass" id="id2"></input>
<input class = "someclass" id="id3"></input>
<input class = "someclass" id="id4"></input>
.
```

Script:

```
 i=0;
    $('.someclass').focus();
    $("#button").click(function(){ 
    $("#id"+i).val("abc"); 
    });
    i++;
```

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you,

```
 $("#button").click(function(){ 
    $(".someclass").val("abc"); 
    });
```